# Is there any way to save Git history into a ZIP file?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, git-history

I'm a beginner in using Git as version control. I need to compile my Git History and compress it into a ZIP file. But I can't seem to find a way to find the physical file that shows Git History. The IDE I've used to develop my project is VS Code.

Comment: *I need to compile my Git History and compress it into a ZIP file.* Why?

Answer (score 1):

`git` offers a built in way to get the history of a repository in one single file : [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle). Check `git help bundle` for details.

---

The complete state of your repo is stored in the hidden `.git/` directory in the root directory. Archive that directory and you will have a backup of your repo.

Note that the content of that directory is basically already zipped, so there isn't much gain (in bytes) to expect from compressing it.